# How to integrate this exponential function

Tags: integration

How can this be integrated so that there is an answer other than saying $E_i(x)+C$ where $E_i(x)$ is the exponential integral and $C$ is a constant.
$$
\int \dfrac{\mathrm{e}^x}{x} \,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251795/problem-when-integrating-ex-x

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{e^x}xdx=\int\frac{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^k}{k!}}xdx=\int\frac{dx}x+\int\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}dx=\ln(x)+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!k}+C.$$

---

To avoid the singularity at the origin, it may be preferable to consider

$$\int\frac{e^x-1}xdx.$$

Answer (score 0):

this integral has no answer in the known elementary functions, see also the Risch algortihm.

Comment: Risch, I guess.