# How to solve integral $\int_0^t\frac {e^{-\frac{s}{c}}} {a(t-s)+b} ds$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I'm currently trying to solve the following integral, so if anyone could please help me, I would be really grateful.

The integral is as follows:

> $$\int_0^t\frac {e^{-\frac{s}{c}}} {a(t-s)+b}   ds,$$

where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are constants.

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate ?   Look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251795/problem-when-integrating-ex-x

Comment: This is not a fair behaviour. If a question of yours gets closed or deleted, the best course of action is to improve it and push for undeletion, not to post it again, unchanged.

Comment: As already mentioned (in agreement with Isham's comment above), this is just an instance of a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral. *Please* have a look at that page.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think I am not seeing the same you are seeing here, can you please explain again? thank you

Comment: @MiguelPais: I wholeheartedly suggest you to revisit the basics of Calculus before trying to tackle complex integrals. I think to have provided you a clear path: enforce the substitution $s\mapsto cu$, then the substitution $a(t-cu)+b\mapsto v$, then the properties of the exponential function, then the definition of the exponential integral. I haven't much to add here, you should perform a bit of work on your own. That applies to the actual question, too: in its current state, it clearly lacks some context.