# Exponential integral with integration variable multiplied with a complex number

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers, exponential-function, complex-integration

I was working on my project, and I came across this integration. After googling, I realized that this is an Exponential Integral. And I'm pretty much new to this. Here is the integration

\begin{equation} 
\int_{R_{min}}^{R_{max}} \frac{e^{-\alpha r}}{r}dr
\end{equation}

Here $R_{max}$ & $R_{min}$ is a real numbers like 160 and 50 respectively.

$\alpha$ is a **complex number** $\alpha = i \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}$ , here $i$ is $\sqrt{-1}$ and $\lambda$ is a real number .

I have no idea how to evaluate this integral. In my project, I've expressed all the results in terms of $\alpha$. Can you give me any result that can be represented as $\alpha$.
Like
\begin{equation} 
\int_{R_{min}}^{R_{max}} e^{-\alpha r}dr
\\
=\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha R_{min}}}{\alpha}-\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-\alpha R_{max}}}{\alpha}
\end{equation}

This above integration is represented in terms of $\alpha$, and I can simply write the code in MATLAB.

Can you give me some results like this one?

Comment: Is $\lambda$ a wavelength? Is this a wave propagation or scattering problem? If so, are you sure this isn't meant to be a three dimensional integral?

Comment: @JohnBarber Yes, it is a wavelength. But this is associated with a drone location and represented in spherical coordinate and the three coordinates are independent that's why I've separated them and I have a single integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Definitions):
$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{e^{-at}}tdt=E_1(a x_1)-E_1(a x_2).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm curious to know how did you calculate this one from the definition? I mean to say in the definition the complex argument is in the limit then how to come up with this solution?

Comment: Use substitution $u=at$ in $\int_x^\infty\frac{e^{-at}}tdt$.

Comment: Just curious to know how to do the same integration when I have $\begin{equation} 
\int_{R_{min}}^{R_{max}} \frac{e^{\alpha r}}{r}dr
\end{equation}$. Just negative value is now positive .

Comment: @AmartyaRoy This results in the replacement $a\to -a$ in both sides of the equation.

Comment: I also thought the same. But when I change $a\to -a$ the $\infty$ changes to $-\infty$. I don't think I can further use the formula of Exponential Integration anymore. I also found in this article that this might be a [Asymptotic expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251795/problem-when-integrating-ex-x). But they're using a real value of $x$ but in my case, I've $\alpha$ as Complex. So, I guess I'll have to use the first 100 or 200 terms to get an approximation. Can you comment on this?

Comment: One should of course be careful. The definition of the exponential integral assumes that $\Re(a)>0$.  You should just do not forget that $E_1(z)$ is the analytic continuation of the integral on the whole complex plane. Therefore the given formula is applicable for arbitrary values of $a$. There can be however issues with numerical evaluation of $E_1(z)$.  I cannot help in this issue but it is certainly solved.