# What is the way to calculate $I_{t}^{+}\left(a;\lambda\right)=\int_{0}^{t}e^{a \times e^{-2\lambda s}}ds$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $a$ and $\lambda$ be two strictly positive real numbers. How do you compute the following integral ?

$$I_{t}^{+}\left(a;\lambda\right)=\int_{0}^{t}e^{a \times e^{-2\lambda s}}ds$$

A priori, we cannot rely on the Exponential Integral as, given the value $a$ and $\lambda$, this means using diverging integrals...

Comment: Is that a cross product or multiplication sign?

Comment: Multiplication sign

Answer (score 0):

> Compute the following integral
> $$I_{t}^{+}\left(a;\lambda\right)=\int_{0}^{t}e^{ae^{-2\lambda s}}ds$$
> where $a,\lambda\in\mathbb{R_+}$.

Substitute $ae^{-2\lambda s}=x$ so that
\begin{align*}
I_t^+(a;\lambda)&=-\frac1{2\lambda}\int_a^{ae^{-2\lambda t}} \frac{e^x}xdx\\
\end{align*}
Let's integrate the more general
\begin{align*}
I&=\int\frac{e^x}xdx\\
&=\int\left(\frac1{x}-\frac1{x^2}+\frac1{x^2}-\frac2{x^3}+\frac2{x^3}-\frac6{x^4}+\cdots\right)e^xdx\\
&=\int\left(\frac1{x}-\frac1{x^2}\right)e^xdx+\int\left(\frac1{x^2}-\frac2{x^3}\right)e^xdx+\int\left(\frac2{x^3}-\frac6{x^4}\right)e^xdx+\cdots\\
&=e^x\left(\frac1{x}+\frac1{x^2}+\frac2{x^3}+\frac6{x^4}+\cdots\right)\\
\end{align*}
Also, see [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251795/problem-when-integrating-ex-x)

Comment: Thanks! But the integral would be $\ln x+ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!n}$